# Move icon inside input field

Tags: html, css

I have an icon inside my input field with the following code:

```
<input type="text" id="checkoutField" value="mail@gmail.com">
```

and the icon is placed at the right, with the help of these CSS lines:

```
background: #f5f5f5 url(http://i.imgur.com/5xD8KRw.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;
```

The icon is touching the right side of the input field, is there a way to get some spacing in between?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6q4Lbqj4/ ..Margin or padding doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: you can use any numbers/values http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-position

Answer (score 5):

You can set your background position to something like:

```
background-position: right 10px top 9px;
```

This code basicly says that you want your background 10px from the right side and 9px from the top. See: http://w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position

Comment: The pixel values of `background-position` are always from `top` and `left`.

Comment: Not since  css3. See examples from
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position

Comment: Quote from my link in previous comment: "If three or four values are given, then each <percentage> or<length> represents an offset and must be preceded by a keyword, which specifies from which edge the offset is given. For example, ‘background-position: bottom 10px right 20px’ represents a ‘10px’ vertical offset up from the bottom edge and a ‘20px’ horizontal offset leftward from the right edge. If three values are given, the missing offset is assumed to be zero."

Comment: Why would anyone want do downvote this valid answer?

Comment: I changed my downvote to an upvote, and because I felt bad, I gave you another (on a different answer of yours, that was also very good)

Answer (score 0):

## Percentages

CSS has percentages, a measurement relative to the parent bloc, this means that an element with a width of `90%`, inside of a container with a width of `100px` will be 90px. You could set a value in pixels, but if the size of your input changes, the image won't respond.

### Solution:

We're going to set the `background-position` to `90%`, or `10%` from the right. If you want, you can also change the `padding-right` to a percentage, and it'll be more responsive.

```css
#checkoutField {
 height: 40px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 50px;
 
    background: #f5f5f5 url(http://i.imgur.com/5xD8KRw.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 90%;
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="checkoutField" value="mail@gmail.com">
```

## Right Position

CSS3 also added `background-position: right 10px center;`, which means `10px` away from the right, centered in all other directions (vertical only for this example). The `center` is required.

So:

```css
#checkoutField {
 height: 40px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 50px;
 
    background: #f5f5f5 url(http://i.imgur.com/5xD8KRw.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: right 10px center;
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="checkoutField" value="mail@gmail.com">
```